# How to solve : "ReferenceError: expect is not defined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm following [this egghead tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-object-mutations-with-object-assign-and-spread) and getting the error in console:

```
"ReferenceError: expect is not defined
    at testToggleTodo (myproj.js:18:3)
    at myproj.js:25:1
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.0.4.min.js:1:13850
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.0.4.min.js:1:10792"
```

**My HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

  <script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/expect@latest"></script>
  <script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/deep-freeze@latest"></script>

  </head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**ES6/Babel**:

```
const toggleTodo = (todo) => {
  todo.completed = !todo.completed;
  return todo;
};

const testToggleTodo = () => {
  const todoBefore = {
    id: 0,
    text: 'Learn Redux',
    completed: false
  };
  const todoAfter = {
    id: 0,
    text: 'Learn Redux',
    completed: true
  };

  expect(
    toggleTodo(todoBefore)
  ).toEqual(todoAfter);
};

testToggleTodo();
console.log('All Tests Passed.');
```

You can see I've imported `expect` in the `head` of my HTML:

`<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/expect@latest"></script>`

Why am I still getting the error? What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: works for me. which browser are you using, and where do you link to your `myproj.js` script from the html?

Comment: I'm using Chrome `Version 60.0.3112.101 (Official Build) (64-bit)`. I copied it to the new `JS Bin` project and getting the same. Just don't understand what I'm missing.

Comment: where is the link to your jsbin project and I will have a look. Also if you just add `<script src="myscripts.js"></script>` to your html, as @Kyon said it should work for you

Comment: Rebooted the computer. Started again. It worked. I did not have to add the `myscripts.js` to my html. Thanks for looking into it. Still clueless why this happened. Don't think any issue with JSBIN. I tried in incognito first and then in normal Chrome. Worked in both.